# Chandra, Fire of Kaladesh as commander

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, mtg-tiny-leaders

If I take Chandra, Fire of Kaladesh as commander (edh or tiny), is it still my commander when it's turned to planeswalker face? If so, can it be returned to command zone when it changes zone  (hand, graveyard, exile)?

Comment: Might be worth editing the linked question, as it only talks about the commander becoming a colorless forest and being turned face-down (à la being manifested), and not being transformed.

Comment: Ok the linked question is answering this one but keep this question alife as it is a good redirection point. Thanks

Comment: agreed, this question is more searchable